# Extracting symbols from strings

Tags: regex, perl

I have some strings, such as the ones below, for an investing club project (and I am a non techie).

Possible strings:

```
$EXPE - Analysts' Actions: TZOO, MSFT, GOOG, ....
$V - Analysts' Actions: TZOO, MSFT, GOOG, ....
$HPQ - Analysts' Actions: TZOO, MSFT, GOOG, ...
```

I want to extract `"EXPE"`, `"V"`, `"HPQ"` from the above lines and other similar strings where the symbol could be 1-4 characters (e.g. $V, $GOOG, $VMW), etc.

I am only able to extract if the company symbol is a fixed length - any pointers?

Comment: The "beginning-of-line" symbol is `^`. Character classes are notated like `[A-Z]`. And variable-length quantifiers are notated like this: `{1,4}`.

Comment: Why does it have to be Perl? Or use regex? That is, why can't you use `cut -d' ' -f1 stocks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extracts all symbols from line

```
# you also need to check word boundaries.
my @symbols = $string =~ m/(\b[A-Z]{1,4}\b)/g
```

Obviously I cannot read the question correctly.

```
my $symbol = $string =~ /\$([A-Z]+)/;
```

Others are correct.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' .. below is what i tried
$linesymbol =~ /\$([A-Z]+)/;

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
^\$([A-Z]{1,4})
```

This looks for a `$` from the beginning of the string followed by 1 to 4 uppercase a-z characters.

You can read more about the `{1,4}` quantifier and other meta characters here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: What happens if you remove the start of string meta character, `^`?

Answer (score 1):

```
my $string = q<$EXPE - Analysts' Actions: TZOO, MSFT, GOOG>;
my ($company_symbol) = $string =~ /^\$([A-Z]{1,4})/;
print "got $company_symbol from $string\n";
```

Comment: Thanks.. trying to see what is up with the syntax.. since i get this when trying it "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/'"